# How to set the state with AASM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

I am attempting to build a learning application that has a quiz on it. The quiz is made up of several steps.

I am using `aasm` to track the the user's state on the quiz. 
There are 3 states:

```
1.not started (Default state)

2.in progress 

3.completed
```

I am tracking the state because when a user starts the quiz, logs out and then returns they will be able to continue.

There are 2 event transitions: 
`start` & `finish`

I understand that I call these on quiz to set the state - `Quiz.start!` & `Quiz.finish!`

I can tell what state the user is on if the quiz step they're on has a parent then they're in progress and if the quiz step they're on has no children then they have finished. Something like this:

```
if quiz.parent
  quiz.start!
else quiz.children == 0
  quiz.finish!
end
```

All I want to know is where I put the above logic to set the state? I don't think I put it in my controller.
Do I have to put it in the Quiz class? 
Do I use a define a method set_state with the above logic in it? 
If so, how do I use it?

I have read the `aasm` docs and kind of get it but my brain is fried and could just use a bit of guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can put this in the controller, or define a new method on the model, it's up to preference. can you show the controller code where you are thinking of putting it?

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly. It is just in my quiz#show action which is currently empty. If I define a method in the model then how do I use it? Can I call it in the show action? Sorry I am sure this is such a basic question but I cannot think!

Comment: if you define a method on the model you call it on an instance of the model. yes you can do it from the show action.

Comment: I guess it's better to put this kinds of logic in your model so that you can access it easier in everywhere ! @Koko